# Add ui hierarchy into the project generated by unity

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine

I construct ui hierarchy in xcode 6, then add them into the project generated by unity 4.6. here is where i add ui code:

```
- (void)showGameUI
{
    ...
    // UI hierarchy
    self.navigationC = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
    _window.rootViewController = self.navigationC;
    _window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    ...
}
```

The showGameUI is located in UnityAppController+ViewHandling.mm. I replace the rootViewController of window, so it should be a white display when app launch. But now, it shows the display implemented in unity.

This is original code:

```
- (void)showGameUI
{
     ...
    // UI hierarchy
    [_window addSubview: _rootView];
    _window.rootViewController = _rootController;
    [_window bringSubviewToFront: _rootView];
    ...
}
```

I replace rootViewController of window, make _rootController as a controller of the whole controllers map. This solution is not work this time, I am so confused. Could you help me? Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the problem. My workmate who is unity guy, bury a bug in unity project. I am a ios developer, my job is work on the ios project generated by unity, so I know little about unity, I can't explain what bug is, and why it comes.